# Get Max value from range (multiple sheets) grouped by Name

Tags: google-sheets

I have 3 sheets that have the exact same format

**Sheet1**

```
A           B          C         D
George      10         2         8
Nick        15         89        0
Mike        13         1         50
Lucas       9         -5         12
```

**Sheet2**

```
A           B          C         D
Nick        1          9         5
Mike        1          10        6
George      11         22        5
Lucas       10         5         2
Panos       55         0         1
```

**Sheet3**

```
A            B         C         D
Panos        0         9         1
George       1         2         5
Nick         7         2         1
Lucas        1         5         1
```

I want to query the range {'Sheet1'!A1:D5; 'Sheet2'!A1:D5; 'Sheet3'!A1:D5}

And get something like MAX(Col2:Col4) Group By Col1

Which would return something like:

```
George 22
Nick   89
Mike   50
Lucas  12
Panos  55
```

I tried:

```
=sort(query({'Sheet1'!A1:D5; 'Sheet2'!A1:D5;'Sheet3'!A1:D5}, "select Col1, MAX(Col2:Col4) Group by Col1 Label MAX(Col2:Col4) '' " ),2, FALSE)
```

and

```
=sort(query({'Sheet1'!A1:D5; 'Sheet2'!A1:D5;'Sheet3'!A1:D5}, "select Col1, MAX(MAX(Col2),MAX(Col3), MAX(Col4)) Group by Col1 " ),2, FALSE)
```

Both didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @I'-'I thats actually a pretty decent solution! Thanks
Consider answering the question normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
=query(sort(transpose(query({Sheet1!A1:D5;Sheet2!A1:D5;Sheet3!A1:D5},"select max(Col2), max(Col3), max(Col4) pivot Col1"))),"select Col1, max(Col2) group by Col1 label(Col1) ''")
```

Comment: Even though I ended up using I'-'I method because I actually liked the idea of having Max stats in each sheet as well, this is the best answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

To sum up your question, It requires finding the `MAX` across the columns to the right as well as down. As such, `QUERY` does NOT have such 2D function.

So, Use a Helper column E&F in **each** sheet:

#### Max of B&C:

E2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B>C2:C,B2:B,C2:C))
```

#### Max of B,C&D:

F2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D>E2:E,D2:D,E2:E))
```

Now, Use Query:

#### Query:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Sheet1!A2:F;Sheet2!A2:F;Sheet3!A2:F}, "Select Col1,max(Col5) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by max(Col5) desc"))
```

Notes:

- Change ranges to suit
- You could also simply use `MAX` for each row without the `ARRAYFORMULA`
- Theoretically,  For a single cell solution, You could enter this [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/89702) to find the max of 3 real numbers

Answer (score 0):

Another approach perhaps a bit simpler but needing two queries

```
=sort(unique(({Sheet1!A1:A5;Sheet2!A1:A5;Sheet3!A1:A5})))
```

to get the names starting in (say) F2

Then this to get the maximum values for each name in (say) G2 and pulled down

```
max(query({Sheet1!A$1:D$5;Sheet2!A$1:D$5;Sheet3!A$1:D$5},"select max(Col2),max(Col3),max(Col4) where Col1='"&F2&"'"))
```